# Windows 7 dual installation on one computer

Tags: windows-7, memory, multi-boot

Please help me decide whether I sould install windows 7 two times on my computer.

My reason for this is as follows:

In many cases new software installation on Windows system means slowing down the computer. There is no such problem in linux systems, where you are asked to autostart certain services; unfortunately for Windows even if you don't choose autostart option you will have some background autoupdater or shell integration which will slow down your system (not to mention growing library of file associations and so on)

I will be using my machine both for 'work/home projects' and for 'entertainment'. In case of work, I will have some RAM-hungry apps such as photoshop, flash, archicad, video vegas, .net visual studio '10. As for entertainment, there will be a lot of small apps (I like to play with them and check out what's new) and some games.

I am afraid that having tonnes of software will kill the performance of my computer, which is baaad :/

Should I do the double Win7 install (work / entertainment) or maybe you have other idea what to do?

Comment: You should be aware that if you intend to use two installations of Windows then **both** of those installations will need to be individually licenced, as in you will need to purchase two copies of Windows.  See the SU Blog post about [Windows Licencing](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/06/microsoft-licencing-transferring-windows-to-another-computer/).

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it. It's possible to reduce the amount of things that run on startup by using something like Sysinternals Autoruns. For testing apps out (depending on requirements, that is) I would install them in a Virtual Machine (VM, look at VirtualBox) and then if they are what you want install them on your main machine.

At the end of the day it's up to you.